# Looking for a working example of D3 JS Bubble Chart?

Tags: d3.js

I can't seem to find any example online for how to create a basic HelloWorld Bubble Chart using D3 JS. Everything seems to use a CSV file like it's the 1990's. No-one is visualising data using JavaScript using a CSV file in 2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of Q&A on the D3 Support Forums (aka. GitHub Discussions), managed to piece together a working example. Including below for others and future reference to help people get started.

Please note: This is for Version 7 of D3 which is the latest version at the time of writing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="module">

import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm";

const svg = BubbleChart([["Hello", 10], ["World", 20]]);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-chart
function BubbleChart(data, {
  name = ([x]) => x, // alias for label
  label = name, // given d in data, returns text to display on the bubble
  value = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns a quantitative size
  group, // given d in data, returns a categorical value for color
  title, // given d in data, returns text to show on hover
  link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
  linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links, if any
  width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
  height = width, // outer height, in pixels
  padding = 3, // padding between circles
  margin = 1, // default margins
  marginTop = margin, // top margin, in pixels
  marginRight = margin, // right margin, in pixels
  marginBottom = margin, // bottom margin, in pixels
  marginLeft = margin, // left margin, in pixels
  groups, // array of group names (the domain of the color scale)
  colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of colors (for groups)
  fill = "#ccc", // a static fill color, if no group channel is specified
  fillOpacity = 0.7, // the fill opacity of the bubbles
  stroke, // a static stroke around the bubbles
  strokeWidth, // the stroke width around the bubbles, if any
  strokeOpacity, // the stroke opacity around the bubbles, if any
} = {}) {
  // Compute the values.
  const D = d3.map(data, d => d);
  const V = d3.map(data, value);
  const G = group == null ? null : d3.map(data, group);
  const I = d3.range(V.length).filter(i => V[i] > 0);

  // Unique the groups.
  if (G && groups === undefined) groups = I.map(i => G[i]);
  groups = G && new d3.InternSet(groups);

  // Construct scales.
  const color = G && d3.scaleOrdinal(groups, colors);

  // Compute labels and titles.
  const L = label == null ? null : d3.map(data, label);
  const T = title === undefined ? L : title == null ? null : d3.map(data, title);

  // Compute layout: create a 1-deep hierarchy, and pack it.
  const root = d3.pack()
      .size([width - marginLeft - marginRight, height - marginTop - marginBottom])
      .padding(padding)
    (d3.hierarchy({children: I})
      .sum(i => V[i]));

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  const leaf = svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("a")
      .attr("xlink:href", link == null ? null : (d, i) => link(D[d.data], i, data))
      .attr("target", link == null ? null : linkTarget)
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

  leaf.append("circle")
      .attr("stroke", stroke)
      .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
      .attr("fill", G ? d => color(G[d.data]) : fill == null ? "none" : fill)
      .attr("fill-opacity", fillOpacity)
      .attr("r", d => d.r);

  if (T) leaf.append("title")
      .text(d => T[d.data]);

  if (L) {
    // A unique identifier for clip paths (to avoid conflicts).
    const uid = `O-${Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)}`;

    leaf.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => `${uid}-clip-${d.data}`)
      .append("circle")
        .attr("r", d => d.r);

    leaf.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => `url(${new URL(`#${uid}-clip-${d.data}`, location)})`)
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(d => `${L[d.data]}`.split(/\n/g))
      .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", (d, i, D) => `${i - D.length / 2 + 0.85}em`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, D) => i === D.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
        .text(d => d);
  }

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {scales: {color}});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```